# Under Eclipse,can I add those automatic indent line that marks the scope of a class, or a method

Tags: eclipse

Under Eclipse,how can I add those automatic indent line that marks the scope of a class, or a method.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual**: Select all <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> 
**Automatic**: Preferences -> Save actions -> Additional Actions -> Configure -> Correct Indentation